# Is asking for robux off-topic?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, asking

I have learned that game piracy is considered off-topic in Arqade.

Does it also count as off-topic if we ask how to get free robux in [roblox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roblox)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Asking for users to give you free robux (or for that matter, any in-game currency) is definitely off-topic. We're a site about getting expert answers to gaming questions, rather than about requests for resources (free or otherwise).

However, if Robux is a currency that can be **earned** in-game, then asking for ways to earn robux (using tricks or methods that are easy/quick/repeatable etc) - that sort of question would be on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

To add onto what @Robotnik said, even if you can't earn robux in game (which it seems like you can't, but nevertheless) it's still on-topic to ask *if there is a way to get them at all,* and it is not restricted to having to be obtainable without actually paying.